# VS2015 compile error for template function with "endl"

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// move operation is not implicitly generated for a class where the user has explicitly declared a destructor
class A {
public:
    friend inline void operator << (ostream &os, A& a) {
        os << "done" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void done(T a) {
    cout << a;
}

template<typename T>
void g(T h) {
    cout << h << endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    done(a);
    // g(a); // with error: "mismatch in formal parameter list" and '<<': unable to resolve function overload.
    return 0;
}
```

As the comments, it is so weird that with 'endl', the code cannot be compiled
with error: "mismatch in formal parameter list" and '<<': unable to resolve function overload.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;` but rather explicitly prefix `std::`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a reference to the stream so that you can chain the function calls

```
friend inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, A& a) {
    os << "done" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Not this

```
friend inline void operator << (ostream &os, A& a) {
    os << "done" << endl;
}
```

When you use

```
friend inline void operator << (ostream &os, A& a)
```

the line

```
cout << h << endl;
```

is a problem since there is no `operator<<` between `void` and `endl`.